# Hermitian Matrices with Repeated Eigenvalues has Codimension 3?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

It is sometimes claimed that

> the space of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices with at least one repeated eigenvalue has codimension 3.

(See [link](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/) exercise 10.)

The proof of this in dimension two is very simple: by diagonalizing a $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrix $H$,
we easily conclude that if $H$ has the same eigenvalue twice,
then $H$ must be a constant multiple of the $2\times 2$ identity matrix,
and this space has dimension 1, versus 4 for the space of $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrices.

However,
I'm having difficulties with (what I believe to be) the *standard* demonstration of this in higher dimensions (provided in the paper "On the Behaviour of Eigenvalues in Adiabatic Processes" by Von Neumann and Wigner).
From what I can tell,
the demonstration (outline) goes goes as follows:

1. An $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $H$ can be written as $UDU^*$,
   where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal and contains the eigenvalues, say in increasing order.
2. The decomposition $UDU^*$ is not unique,
   but if we have $WDW^*$ for another unitary matrix $W$,
   then we can write $W=UV$, where $V$ commutes with $D$,
   and so one could argue we can fix $U$ and $D$,
   and then write $H=(UV)D(UV)^*$,
   where $V$ can be any unitary matrix that commutes with $D$.
3. Thus, the number of real parameters one needs to specify the matrix $H$ would be $n^2+f-v$, where $n^2$ is the number of real parameters to specify a fixed unitary matrix $U$, $f$ is the number of parameters to specify the real eigenvalues of $D$, and $v$ is the number of parameters to specify $V$.
4. We can show that, if $f$ is the number of eigenvalues of $H$, and $g_1,\ldots,g_f$ are the multiplicities of the eigenvalues (i.e., $g_1+\cdots+g_f=n$), then $v=g_1^2+g_2^2+\cdots+g_f^2$.
5. Therefore,
   if there is a repeated eigenvalue ($g_i\geq 2$ for at least one $i$),
   the number of parameters will be at most $n^2-3$,
   hence the space of Hermitian matrices with repeated eigenvalues has codimension 3.

My problems with this are the following:

- In the case of $2\times 2$ matrices, it is clear that the space of Hermitian matrices with repeated eigenvalues is a vector space, as it consists of the multiples of the identity matrix. However, it is not at all clear to me that this is the case in higher dimensions.
- In step 3. above, I don't understand how one just *removes* the parameters used to specify $V$ from the total amount of parameters. If it were argued that we have *double counted* some parameters and that we must now remove them, this would be fine, but it seems that we start with $n^2+f$ parameters and that we then somehow remove parameters that are completely unrelated to the previous ones.
- Finally, I'm not sure I understand the connection between *parameters* and dimension.  While it is true that Unitary matrices can be specified with $n^2$ numbers, we can't say that the space of Unitary matrices has dimension $n^2$ because unitary matrices do not form a linear subspace. So, I'm not sure how this business of counting parameters rigorously coincides with dimension of subspaces.

Comment: In the statement "the space of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices with at least one repeated eigenvalue has codimension 3", the word _dimension_ does not refer to dimensions of linear subspaces, but instead to dimensions of (nonlinear) [submanifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) and [varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety).  The argument you give is using fairly standard techniques to determine the dimension of this variety.

Comment: @JimBelk Could you perhaps briefly describe how this parameter counting can be made into a rigorous determination of the codimension?

Answer (score 1):

Let $K_n$ be the set of hermitian matrices of dimension $n$. Note that
$E_n=\{H\in K_n|card(spectrum(H))\leq n-1\}$ is a REAL algebraic set
and $dim(E_n)$ is the greatest dimension of its components. A
component of maximal dimension is obtained by considering $F_n=\{H\in
K_n|card(spectrum(H))= n-1\}$. We consider the function $f:(U,D)\in
U(n)\times DR\rightarrow UDU^*\in F_n$ where
$DR=\{diag((\lambda_i)_i)|\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R},\lambda_1=\lambda_2\}$.
The stabilizer, $R=\{V\in U(n)|VD=DV\}=\{V\in
U(n)|V=diag(T_2,\mu_3,\cdots,\mu_n)\}\approx U(2)\times (S_1)^{n-2}$,
has real dimension $2^2+1+\cdots+1=n+2$; thus we obtain the real
dimension $dim(F_n)=dim(U(n)\times DR)-dim(R)=n^2+(n-1)-(n+2)=n^2-3$.

Remark. $E_n=\{H\in K_n|discrim(\det(H-xI_n),x)=0\}$. Note that
$p(H)=discrim(\det(H-xI_n),x)\in\mathbb{Z}[(u_{ij})_{ij}]$ where the
$u_{ij}$ are the $n^2$ real parameters that define $K_n$. The previous result
says that $p=0$ can be decomposed in $3$ independent real algebraic relations.